# Read android device unique ID, create a QR Code URL and make the browser open the URL

Tags: java, android, qr-code

I'm looking to read the android device unique id (mac address or android ID) and basically embed that into a QR COde types URL and ask the browser to open that URL. What is the best way to go about this in android, use a separate app? Or do it via the settings app? In the long run, this URL will point to a webserver which will read the URL, specifically the unique id and see if there is something that needs to be pushed to this unique id device.

Comment: What do you mean by QR Code type URL?

Comment: Like this http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=300x300&chl=UNIQUEID  where UNIQUEID is android device ID or mac address. chart.apis.google is for creating QRCODE, which i will replace later with a server address of choice.

Comment: This is a discussion of unique IDs in android: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html, what I usually do is generate a unqiue id myself, and store it in preferences.

Comment: I guess the important thing i am looking for is how to pass this URL to a web browser to launch it, some sort of service i am thinking. Creating the URL is easy but i want it to be passed to the browser and launch it on the device. what's the best way?

Comment: You'll need to launch an intent. Are you doing this from an android application? What initiates the action?

Comment: prob something like this is what i was thinking Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
      Uri.parse("http://almondmendoza.com/android-applications/"));
startActivity(i); I have to think about where to initiate this from, if i want to do it on a periodic basis. I might make it a enable/disable option within settings